# Merge sort could work 10 times faster

Tags: java, performance, sorting, mergesort

I am implementing merge sort in Java and I have a performance problem in this method:

```
    private static void marge(int[] source, int[] buffer, int startingIndex, int count) {
        int index1 = startingIndex;
        int index2 = startingIndex + count / 2;
        int maxIndex1 = index2;
        int maxIndex2 = startingIndex + count;

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            if(index2 >= maxIndex2 || (index1 < maxIndex1 && source[index1] < source[index2])){
                buffer[startingIndex + i] = source[index1];
                index1++;
            }
            else{
                buffer[startingIndex + i] = source[index2];
                index2++;
            }
        }

//      System.arraycopy(source, startingIndex, buffer, startingIndex, count);
    }
```

If I replace this method content with the content of the comment, like this:

```
private static void marge(int[] source, int[] buffer, int startingIndex, int count) {
    System.arraycopy(source, startingIndex, buffer, startingIndex, count);
}
```

It performs **10 to 20 times faster**. I understand that I have more calculations in my original method but "10 to 20 times" seems too much for me.

Do you have any idea how to improve performance?

Comment: `System.arraycopy` calls native code, so it will always be *much* faster: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.arraycopy%28java.lang.Object%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cint%2Cint%29

Comment: @konjin out of pure interest.. if you implemented the same algorithm like the native code one, how much faster would it be when written in native code?

Comment: Who is marge?  Please update the function name to something meaningful -- did you mean "merge"?

Comment: @Vogel612 - This is almost impossible to do since native code (machine language) allows you to copy data with a single instruction cf http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOV_%28x86_instruction%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some pointers:

- You keep adding 2 numbers here: `startingIndex + i`, that could probably be avoided if you went `for(int i = startIndex; i < lastIndex; i++){` where `lastIndex` would be `startIndex + count`
- Since `++` happens post evaluation you could simply do `buffer[startingIndex + i] = source[index1++];`, it does not have to be a separate statement
- Short circuit logic : if `index2 >= maxIndex2`, then you should probably have a  `System.arraycopy` copy that fills the rest into `index1` and get out. You could the same for when `index1 > maxIndex1` but obviously you would fill into `index2` then

From a naming perspective, I would rather read `upperIndex` and `lowerIndex` than `index1` and `index2`

Totally untested, I would try something like this:

```
private static void merge(int[] source, int[] buffer, int startingIndex, int count) {
    int lowerIndex = startingIndex;
    int lowerBound = startingIndex + count / 2;
    int upperIndex = lowerBound;
    int upperBound = startingIndex + count;

    for(int i = startingIndex ; i < upperBound ; i++){
        if(upperIndex >= upperBound ){
          System.arraycopy(source, lowerIndex , buffer, i, i - startingIndex );
          return;
        }
        if(lowerIndex >= lowerBound ){
          System.arraycopy(source, upperIndex , buffer, i, i - startingIndex );
          return;
        }
        buffer[i] = source[lowerIndex] < source[upperIndex] ? source[lowerIndex++] : source[upperIndex++]
    }
}
```